# Regexp To Match Characters after string

Tags: regex

I want to match the string that comes after http://test.website.com/Account/ActivateAccount/.

E.g.:

The string to be evaluated:

http://test.website.com/Account/ActivateAccount/bba29f0c-f0e0-4e3a-93dd-e10a090c3f29

Desired Outcome:

bba29f0c-f0e0-4e3a-93dd-e10a090c3f29

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Got an answer now thanks anyway, Amit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match just GUIDs, you can use:

```
\/((\w{8}(?:-\w{4}){3}-\w{12}))$
```

Example here:https://regex101.com/r/iW6fH2/1

if you want to match every text and the beginning part of the address is fixed, you can use:

```
http\:\/\/test\.website\.com\/Account\/ActivateAccount\/(.*)
```

Example here:https://regex101.com/r/jF8oI1/1